# Calculate Laurent Series for $\frac{\ln z}{(z-1)^3}$ about $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

Calculate the Laurent series of the function $g(z)= \frac{\ln z}{(z-1)^3}$ about the point $z=1$.

Well since the singularity and the centre of the circle we are expanding about collide, I can just bring about the $\frac{1}{(z-1)^3}$. But what do I do with the $\ln z$? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = z - 1$. Then
$$
g(z) = \frac{\ln(u + 1)}{u^3}
$$
The series expansion of 
$$
\ln(u + 1) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}u^n
$$
Now divide the expanded terms by $u^3$ and make the substitution $u = z - 1$.

Answer (score 2):

You need the Laurent series for $\ln z = (z-1) - \frac{1}{2} (z-1)^2 + \frac{1}{3} (z-1)^3 -\cdots$.
The rest should be easy.

Comment: Thanks! That's all I was missing.