# How to Integrate$\int_C\frac{Log~z}{(z-i)^2}$ where $C:|z-i|=1$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, laurent-series

Let $C:|z-i|=\alpha$,where $0<\alpha<1$
I need to evaluate this expression

> $~\int_C\frac{Log~z}{(z-i)^2}$

what I tried to do was representing $Log~z$ as a Laurent series on $|z-1|<1$.
But what I can think is only about $\frac{Log~z}{(z-1)^2}$ as a Laurent series. I don't know how to use what I know and what I don't know yet.

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Now that the OP has edited the question:
Recall Cauchy theorem:
$$f(w) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \dfrac{f(z)}{z-w} dz$$
Differating in respect to $w$ we get: $$f'(w) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-w)^2} dz $$

Can you figure it out from here?

Comment: @Weaam It would, but i figured this is a way to approach to the problem and then assign the cauchy principal value.

Comment: if the curve crossing a "problematic" value - the integral might be not well defined

Comment: @Weaam perhaps use the substitution w=z+1 to transform log z to log (z+1) then(1/w)'?

Comment: @Weaam I don't see any reason that wouldn't work because log (z+1) is well defined and analytic; is it not?

Comment: or maybe you could use the fact that the taylor series of -ln(1-z)=z+z^2/2+... .? en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series

Comment: @Weaam Did it work? There could be some subtle issue. I'm not a very good mathematician. If it works, could you tell me the answer so I can verify it when I have some free time?

Comment: @MadScientist Is there a problem with the solution now?
At first, the OP asked to integrate over a contour that goes *through* the branching point. But after an edit has been made the integral is well-defined and can be calculated without assigning Cauchy principle value.

Comment: @Ranc I'm sorry. I'm too stupid and/or tired to answer (I don't know what a branching point is yet). Did he change his question? I didn't see a change. I just threw out a couple of ideas that may or may not work. That's why I merely commented and didn't actually Answer.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, the OP edited the question. Anyways, your ideas are solid. One can calculate the integral using the Laurent expansion. But, ofcourse, all roads lead to rome

Comment: @Ranc Right. That does have a nice Laurent expansion. I found a similar problem here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024866/calculate-laurent-series-for-frac-ln-zz-13-about-z-1 now I know what a branching point is too. I learn more from other peoples questions than my own.